# How to redirect log but keep existing stdout, stderr, and log4j logs?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am adding a new appender and calling org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(). However, this seems to override the default databricks logging and I can no longer see the logs as normal from driver-logs or executor logs view.

I think databricks probably use some FileAppender. How could I add new appender while keeping existing databricks ones please?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure` yourself to extend the built-in logging configuration. Rather, do it by defining an arbitrarily-named `log4j.properties` file in the `/databricks/spark/conf/` directory. ([reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging)) Also, you might need to use an init-script to ensure that the file is added to all nodes in the cluster.